# Routing in react- Link to or href

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, href, link-to

I'm creating a project in react and I'm having a problem with the href. When I run the project locally with the href everything runs smoothly on the hamburger menu. However when I put it on the server it does not do the routing well.
When I use Link to it works fine but the hamburger menu does not collapse when clicking on the link from another page. Check the site here: http://tinturarianatural.pt/

```
function Header() {
return(

   <div className="nav">
        <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check"/>
        <div className="nav-header">
            <div className="nav-title">
                <Link to="/"><img className="logotipo-header" src={logo} alt="logotipo" /></Link>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="nav-btn">
            <label htmlFor="nav-check">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div className="nav-links">
            <li><Link to="/">INICIO</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/projeto">PROJETO</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/parceiros">PARCERIA</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/plantas">PLANTAS & LÃ</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/recursos">RECURSOS</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/contactos">CONTACTOS</Link></li>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

}

Comment: Do you mean the hamburger menu doesn't collapse automatically?
Because it is when I'm clicking on it.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. When I use the Link to doesn't collapse automatically

Comment: Is the `Header` component outside your `Router` ? That could explain the reason is not refreshed on location changes.

Comment: please upload your code